Is sequence $x_n = A^nBC^n x$ either bounded or distributed linearly?
Given 3 invertible matrices $A,B,C \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$ and a starting vector $x \in \mathbb R^k$, $x\not= 0$, define a sequence $(x_n)$ by $x_n = A^nBC^n\cdot x$.
Is it always the case that $\|x_n\|$ - using Euclidean norm here -  is either bounded or distributed approximately linearly? Meaning that $\#\{n \in \mathbb N\ \ |\ \ \|x_n\| \in [m,m+1]\} \in O(1)$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$.
In my specific use case, all three matrices are of the form
$\begin{pmatrix} M & v \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $M \in O_{k-1}(\mathbb R)$. In other words, one can view $A,B,C$ as isometries of $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ acting as matrices on $\mathbb R^{k-1} \times \{1\}$. I have been able to prove this specific case for $k=3$ using that $M$ will always be a rotation or a reflection, and in the former case $M-I$ is invertible, allowing me to bound the geometric sums occuring in $A^nBC^n$. (To get rid of reflections, one can just look at $(x_{2n})$). But I don't know how to generalize this to larger $k$.
